# Time of answer posted jumped

Tags: support

Am using Chromium version 24.0.1312.52 (175374) under ArchLinux, and have noticed an obscure thing, every-time I post a comment or an answer, it seemingly "jumps"...

Let me explain:

- I post a comment or an answer, as of "right now" (*at the moment I submit*), for example 23:45, Chromium says "x minutes ago", (*in line with the previous example, "**t0mm13b - 14 mins ago**"*) the minute I post the comment, same applies for answers... where x is so far off (either in past or future...)

Has anyone else noticed this or is it a bug in the browser?

Comment: Your system time is close to "real" time I assume? :P

Comment: @MatthewRead ha! NTP is running on the network and is close to real time... xD :D

Answer (score 2):

This can really only mean that your computer's system clock is set incorrectly. We work on the assumption that a visitors system clock is correct; see [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134925/user-reputation-graph-uses-client-date/134929#134929) for some reasoning behind that.